# AWS CDK BasePathMapping already exists error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When trying to deploy a CDK stack with a REST API and an `apigateway.BasePathMapping`, I get the following error:

`<my_domain>|(none) already exists in stack <my_stack_arn>`

I tried deleting the mapping both with the CLI using the [delete-base-path-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/delete-base-path-mapping.html) command and from the user interface but the problem remains.

Deleting the entire stack and re-creating it does not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using AWS CDK and was facing the same issue until I used different base paths for different APIs. Make sure your `basePath` is different for each stage/service.

```
const { RestApi, EndpointType, Cors, DomainName, BasePathMapping } = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway');

const my_apig = new RestApi(this, 'my_apig', {
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: props.env.stage
      },
      endpointConfiguration: {
        types: [EndpointType.REGIONAL]
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
        allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS,
        allowHeaders: Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS,
        allowCredentials: true
      }
});

const myCustomDomain = DomainName.fromDomainNameAttributes(this, 'my-domain', {
      domainName: 'example.com'
});

new BasePathMapping(this, 'base-path-mapping', {
      domainName: myCustomDomain,
      restApi: my_apig,
      basePath: props.env.serviceName    // set this using a dynamic parameter for different stage/service
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be in the order you tried those solutions in.
If you tried to delete the stack without removing mapping, it would error as api gateway might fail to delete(specially if the domain name is pre-exisiting).
If you delete the mapping, then delete the stack and retry, it should work. It should also work if you just delete the mapping and update stack without deleting.
I have it working and creating new mappings each time a new stack is deployed and retaining mapping otherwise with this:

```
let domainName = DomainName.fromDomainNameAttributes(this, 'APIDomainName', {
    domainName: option.domainName,
    domainNameAliasTarget: option.domainNameAliasTarget,
    domainNameAliasHostedZoneId: option.domainNameAliasHostedZoneId
})
new BasePathMapping(this, 'ApiBasePathMapping', {
    domainName: domainName,
    restApi: this._api,
    basePath: 'my-mapping',
    stage: this._api.deploymentStage,
});
```

from here: [CDK docs-Base path mapping](https://from%20here:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.BasePathMapping.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).